# jQuery Stop duplicate append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i'm trying to do here i have 1 select box and one input.

The select box have 3 options with values 1,2 and 3 and the input is in div with id INPUT.

What i want here is when i select the options with value 3 to remove the whole div tag with id INPUT, and then when i click again example on 1 or 2 the DIV tag to append again. But when i'm clicking on 1 or 2 the div tag is appending again and again.

Is there is a chance to check if the div tag exist and not to append.

Here is my jQuery :

```
$('select').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
                if(val == '3'){
                    $('#INPUT').remove();
                    }

                if(val !== '3'){
                $('.valuta').before('<div id="INPUT"><input type="text"  class="price"></div>');

                    }
                });
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen your code and html so I don't now what's appropriate but I thought I'd link you to hide() which would also work - http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I thought about to hide with slide toggle jQuery function but i need to be removed. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Change this:

```
if(val !== '3'){
```

to this:

```
if(val != '3' && $("#INPUT").size() == 0){
```

This way, we're asking if there is already a div with id =  `INPUT`, if there is none, then we add one.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Edgar. This one also works. I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Btw, we should use here :if (val != '3' && !$('#INPUT').size() > 0).

Comment: @user2317735 No, we have to add it if there are *zero* #INPUTs :)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, you're right, I'm a bit outdated. Anyway, it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the element with the id `INPUT` already exists before adding a new one

```
if (val != '3' && !$('#INPUT').length) {
    $('.valuta').before('<div id="INPUT"><input type="text"  class="price"></div>');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mu4M9/)

---

Also you can fine tune the `if` condition because if the value is not 3 then you want to have the input field so there is no need for the second if condition just use `else` block in the first condition

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == '3') {
        $('#INPUT').remove();
    } else if (!$('#INPUT').length) {
        $('.valuta').before('<div id="INPUT"><input type="text"  class="price"></div>');
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/239r8/)